# How to remove pre-selected options when loading select control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am using react-select and pre-selecting options (from state) when it loads. Using multiple select true. 
When I click on Select box it still  shows the options which are already showing up. how to remove those from options list?

this is my code:

```
  const options = []
    {
        deviceData ? deviceData.forEach((element, key) => {
            options.push({ value: element.id, label: element.area })
        }) : null;
    }

         <Select isMulti
                                        isSearchable
                                            value={defaultSelected}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            options={options}
                                        />

            function handleChange(selectedOption) {
                setDefaultSelected(selectedOption)
            };

    async function getRooms(deviceIds) {
        ... // filterring logic to select multiple options load 
    ... filteredDevices.push({ value: index, label: devicesAll.area })
            setDefaultSelected(filteredDevices) // This loads pre-selected values to multi select box. 
    }
```

Updated:
I noticed pre-selection only works (value={defaultSelected}) when i supply value as index. 
so I am passing below as "defaultSelected" value where **value: number**

**may be because of this it does not filter the value from select when it loads?** 
console.log(filteredDevices)

> { id: "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aa9f" label: "Meeting room 2" value: 0 }

[image]

Let me know if you need anymore code to understand this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're wanting "default values" (provided by `defaultSelected`) to be pre-selected on first render, and you'd like these to be changeable by the user during subsequent interaction.

One way would be via the [`defaultValue`](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props) prop which should do what you want:

```
<Select isMulti isSearchable
        defaultValue={defaultSelected} // <-- use defaultValue instead
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options} />
```

So for example, doing something like this:

```
const values = [
  { id: "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aa9f", label: "Meeting room 2", value: 0 },
  { id: "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b11111", label: "Meeting room 1", value: 1 }
];

<Select
    defaultValue={[values[0]]}
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={values} />
```

Here's [a working example showing](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-q3vbg) the above in action

Comment: defaultValue just shows no default selection if I pass same "defaultSelected" value for some reason. i updated question please look

Comment: What is the value of `defaultSelected` when rendering happens?

Comment: [{ id: "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aa9f" label: "Meeting room 2" value: 0 },{ id: "5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b11111" label: "Meeting room 1" value: 1 }] --- its like this.. but different for each of the row

Comment: using this value select box do defaultselect for value: 0 and value: 1 but then again not removing from options

Comment: Strange - does this work for you? See `example.js` : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-q3vbg

Comment: if you can please put your last comment as answer, i can mark as answer,. i got the solution from example.js

Comment: @newdeveloper just extended the answer - glad to hear that it's working for you now :)